# Copy rows from database table to another database table with same structure and where

Tags: sql, mariadb

Well, I would like to copy an entire table that has like 400,000,000 rows in it, but using a where condition, to another table on another database with the same structure.

I let this command executing this night:

```
INSERT INTO db2.tb1 SELECT * from db1.tb1 where column=xxx;
```

But nothing has copied since then. What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

When I isolate the execution this is what happens:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ucpX6e8.png]

**EDIT2**

Setting autocommit to 1:

[image]

Comment: If nothing was copied, then the `where` condition is filtering out al rows.

Comment: Maybe the condition exclude all the data. Did you try execute isolated Select over db2.tb1 and db1.tb1 in the same query context?, for simulation purpose.
We want help but we need more info.

Comment: @MauricioKenny yep, I tried doing `SELECT * FROM db1.tb1 WHERE column=xxx` does work.

Comment: What data type is [column] field?. Can you paste some data?. More explicit.

Comment: Did the execution end with no data copied or the execution didn't end and is still running?

Comment: @MundoPeter one of the executing did finished and the other one no.

Comment: @MauricioKenny is an integer type.
https://i.imgur.com/ucpX6e8.png you can see there that the execution goes well when it's isolated.

Comment: Have some AUTO_INCREMENT column in that tables? You use MariaDB. Share more info, because it's more difficult help with limited info.

Comment: I have AUTO_INCREMENT enabled but set to 0.

Comment: Is autocommit=1? If not, did you forget to commit your transaction? What does ```SELECT ROW_COUNT()``` return after insert into select from ?

Comment: I set autocommit to 1, but I received the following error: `The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size`...